# Nessus on Linux detected SSL version 2 and 3 because of Samba. How to fix it?

Tags: linux, samba, ssl

We are using Nessus to confirm that our server does not have SSL 2 and 3 supported via any of the ports. We came down to the last product - samba (3.6.25.)

This samba version does not support turning ssl off during Configure and build. It requires changes to smb.conf

The problem we have is that despite `ldap ssl = off` (and restarting smbd) Nessus keeps discovering SSL23.

We have current run out of ideas and any query to search for a solution fails so far.

Anyone has solved that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, I have goofed. The problem was *NOT* in SAMBA.

Indeed, `ldap ssl = off` was doing was it was supposed to do, but an other tool of ours, which was starting and stopping with SAMBA, was using SSL3 as the primary protocol. That is why Nessus was finding it. When we forced using TLS1 the problem disappeared.

Thank you for all your help, and I'm sorry for anyone loosing his/her time reading it, and trying to solve.

Blessings,
Greg.

Answer (score 1):

> Nessus on Linux detected SSL version 2 and 3 because of Samba. How to fix it?

First, ensure SAMBA is up-to-date or patched.

Second, ensure its well configured. See, for example, [Disabling SSLv3 on samba](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/187770) on the Linux & Unix Stack Exchange or [Disabling SSLv3 to mitigate POODLE effects](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2014-November/186557.html) on the SAMBA mailing list.

The short answer is it looks like you have to properly configure GnuTLS, which SAMBA appears to depend upon.

---

> The problem we have is that despite ldap ssl = off (and restarting smbd) Nessus keeps discovering SSL23.

In the big picture, file a bug report with the distro or package maintainer. Its clearly a security bug to support SSLv2 and SSLv3 in 2015.

Comment: Dear jww: I'm upping you for your rich response. I have found, however, the problem was not in SAMBA but an other tool of ours, which we did not see starting when SAMBA was on, and when we were stopping SAMBA the tool was also stopping.